# How to manage internationalization with Hugo and NetlifyCMS

Tags: internationalization, translation, hugo, netlify, netlify-cms

I am working on a Hugo site with NetlifyCMS integration (GitLab as backend).
I wanna know what options I have to allow modification of the internationalization files that Hugo uses (`i18n/en.yaml`, `i18n/fr.yaml`, ...) from within the NetlifyCMS admin panel.

It is easy to modify translations of content files (`_index.md`, `_index.fr.md`, ...) by just creating a separate collection for every page and adding each language version of one page under the same collection.

How should I approach the integration of the i18n files with NetlifyCMS? https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/#translation-of-strings

Answer (score 1):

Create a `File Collection` in your `config.yml` for the `i18n` files where there is a file for each language.

```js
  - name: Language
    label: language
    delete: false
    files:
      - name: english
        file: 'i18n/en.yaml'
        label: English
        fields:
          - widget: object
            name: home
            label: Home
            fields:
              - {widget: string, name: other, label: Other, required: true}
          - widget: object
            name: title
            label: 'Site Title'
            fields:
              - {widget: string, name: other, label: Other, required: true}
      - name: french
        file: 'i18n/fr.yaml'
        label: French
        fields:
          - widget: object
            name: home
            label: Home
            fields:
              - {widget: string, name: other, label: Other, required: true}
          - widget: object
            name: title
            label: 'Site Title'
            fields:
              - {widget: string, name: other, label: Other, required: true}
```